# Finding the column number of the smallest element in a certain row

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix

Using R

Say for example you have a matrix such as the one below.

```
    > C<-matrix(c(0,-7,2,8,0,0,3,7,0,3,0,3,0,0,0,0),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)
> C
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0   -7    2    8
[2,]    0    0    3    7
[3,]    0    3    0    3
[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

How do you find the column number of the smallest element in a certain row. For example I want to know what column number the smallest element in row 1 is. Therefore the output should just be 2. As the smallest element in row 1 is -7 and that is in column 2. I'm assuming the answer is very easy but i just can't seem to do it! I tried doing the following but it just gives me the answer of 5.

```
> inds = which(C == min(C[1,]))
> inds
[1] 5
```

Can someone also tell me what the 5 means in this particular case?

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: @JonathanWheeler sorry i just edited it to say this, it is in R.

Comment: The `5` tells you that `-7` is found at the 5th position (row 1 and col2) inside the whole `C` matrix. Instead you meant to do `which(C[1,] == min(C[1,]))`: it would have returned `2`, meaning the second position in the `C[1,]` vector.

Comment: You should use `which(C[1,]==min(C[1,]),arr.ind = T)`, which gives `2`

Answer (score 7):

If there is only a single minimum for each row you can find it with

```
apply(C, 1, which.min)
```

or (from [R: finding column with minimum value in each row when there is a tied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495289/r-finding-column-with-minimum-value-in-each-row-when-there-is-a-tied)). See `?max.col` for more options.

```
max.col(-C, "first")
```

**edit** (thanks to @flodel in the comments)

You can do this for individual rows by

```
which.min(C[1,])
```

Or if there are multiple matches

```
apply(C, 1, function(i) which(i == min(i)))
```

You get `5`, as `-7` is the fifth element of the matrix as it goes column wise. Look at `c(C)`

Comment: I overlooked your solution with `max.col` (+1)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I think the OP is just looking for `which.min(C[1, ])`.

Comment: @flodel; maybies, ill edit to show individual calculatios, thanks

Comment: @user20650 sorry i have one other problem. what if i wanted the minumum element to not equal 0? for example from row 2: which.min(C[2,]) will give the answer as being the second column, but the element it is considering is 0. I want it to produce the solution as the third column as it is the lowest number not equal to 0. I attempted to add a threshold<-0 and then using the which.min(C[2,]!=threshold) but it still gives the second column.

Comment: You can do `which.min(ifelse(C[2, ] == 0, Inf, C[2, ]))`.