# which.min by row without apply

Tags: r, apply, min

I was sure something of the sort would exist (along the lines of `rowSums`, etc), but I couldn't find anything.  Basically, do this:

```
apply(mx, 1, which.min)
```

without using `apply` so that we can avoid the overhead of calling `which.min` `nrow(mx)` times, which could be a large number.

Comment: Does `max.col` help here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404710/finding-the-column-number-of-the-smallest-element-in-a-certain-row

Comment: @user20650, awesome, can't believe I missed it in the docs for `which.min`; please post as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Please feel free to update yours - you've done all the hard work already

Comment: @user20650, I can't even accept my own answer for another two days, so please post your so you can get the rep you deserve!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @user20650 for the answer:

```
set.seed(1)
mx <- matrix(runif(1e7), ncol=5)
```

With `apply`:

```
system.time(which.min.mx <- apply(mx, 1, which.min))
# user  system elapsed 
#  4.7     0.0     4.7
```

with `max.col`:

```
system.time(mx.mins.2 <- max.col(-mx, ties="first"))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.12    0.00    0.13 
all.equal(which.min.mx, mx.mins.2)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

Old answer: This is the best I came up with.  Hopefully somebody has something better like a built in `row.which.min` or some such.  Data:

Using `pmin`, `==`, `%%`, and some vector recycling:

```
system.time({
  row.min <- do.call(pmin, as.data.frame(mx))
  mx.mins <- which(t(mx == row.min)) %% ncol(mx)
  mx.mins[!mx.mins] <- ncol(mx)
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.51    0.00    0.51 
all.equal(which.min.mx, mx.mins)
# [1] TRUE
```

Not to mention this kind of falls flat on its face if there is more than one minimum value in a row.